# Compute the weakest precondition

Tags: preconditions

Compute the weakest precondition for each of the following assignment statements and postconditions:

a = a + 2 * b - 1 {a > 1}

attempt:

a is on both sides

0 = 2b -1

1/2 = b is the weakest precon

answer:
b > 1 - a/2

how do you get this answer?

Comment: Here's one way: Start with `a + 2 * b - 1 > 1` and solve for `b`.

Comment: ok I got it, ty

Comment: @melpomene Can you post your answer? Some people (including me) looks for the first-sight green check symbol.

Answer (score 3):

Here is answer :

```
a = a + 2 * b - 1 {a > 1}
```

We replace `a in {a > 1}` by `a + 2 * b - 1`

```
a + 2 * b - 1 > 1
a + 2 * b > 2
2 * b > 2 - a
b > 1 - a / 2`
```

I think you found the answer since but for the people who might get here looking for this answer.